# How to create a user in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am creating a CMS App where the user should register first.

I created a `RegisterController` where I define `index()` method which returns the view `register.blade.php`!

When the user clicks Register button, the request should pass to `create()` method alongside `/register` URL and create a user.

Since, I already defined that `/register` should open `register.blade.php`, then how can I run another method to create a user under the same URL?

I also don't want to use `php artisan make:controller RegisterController --resource`.

RegisterController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Authentication;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('auth.register');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data) {
        return $data->validate([
            'fname' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'lame' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(Request $request) {
        $this->validator($request->all)->validate();
    }
}
```

register.blade.php

```
@extends('master')

@section('title')
  Register - CMS APP
@endsection

@section('styles')
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/auth.css') }}">
@endsection

@section('register')
  <form class="form-signin" method="post" accept-charset="utf8" action="/register/create">
    @csrf
    <img class="mb-4" src="http://logo.kenh.net/logo/bootstrap-4.svg.png" alt="" width="72" height="72">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please Register</h1>
    <label for="inputFirstName" class="sr-only">First Name</label>
    <input name="fname" type="string" id="inputFirstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" autofocus value="{{old('fname')}}">
    @if($errors->has('fname'))
      <div class="alert-danger">
        <p>First Name is required</p>
      </div>
    @endif
    <label for="inputLastName" class="sr-only">Last Name</label>
    <input name="lname" type="string" id="inputLastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" autofocus value="{{old('lname')}}">
    @if($errors->has('lname'))
      <div class="alert-danger">
        <p>Last Name is required</p>
      </div>
    @endif
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" autofocus value="{{old('email')}}">
    @if($errors->has('email'))
      <div class="alert-danger">
        <p>Email is required</p>
      </div>
    @endif
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input name="password" type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    @if($errors->has('password'))
      <div class="alert-danger">
        <p>Password is required</p>
      </div>
    @endif
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit">Register</button>
    <br>
    <a href="/login" class="btn btn-primary">Login</a>
  </form>
@endsection
```

Routes(web.php):

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('register', 'Authentication\RegisterController@index');

Route::get('/login', function() {
    return view('auth.login');
})->name('login');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use Laravel Auth which will build the auth database, views and logic for you?

```
php artisan make:auth
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication

EDIT:

Ok, so If I understand correctly, you want your post and get pointing to the same route url?

```
Route::match(array('GET','POST'),'/register', 'RegisterController@index');
{
   //
});
```

Comment: Nup. I want to start on my own from scratch!

Comment: Updated my answer @Sanjay

Comment: I get `Attribute [controller] does not exist.`error. I guess controller attribute is no more valid in Laravel 5.6!

Comment: Updated again, my bad.. This is how the larval docs recommend we achieve this. @Sanjay

Comment: How do I point it to a controller? Like `Route::match(array('GET', 'POST'), '/register', 'RegisterController'`

Comment: @Sanjay Updated with controller. Not that you use use Route::any if Route::match will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the routing in this form:

```
Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');
```

This might work for you.

Also, don't forget to go through the official documentation of Laravel regarding Routing.

```
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing
```

This will help you alot.

Answer (score 0):

The form is sending a post request to a certain route which in this case is `/register` but you have not supplied that route yet.

```
Route::post('register', 'Authentication\RegisterController@create');
```

Additionally, your form action can just be `action="register"`